# Assigning items from dictionary's set to a Combobox

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

My plan was to create a combobox with the names of individuals, so that user can select a name from the set and enter its points into the Entry box. I tried to do this, but my drop-down list does not show a list of names in the Individual set, but just all 5 sets: Team1, Team2, Team3, Team4 and Individuals.

Initially, everything is arranged so that the user enters the name of the Individual, which is saved in the dictionary `teams = {... 'Individuals': set()}` after which the names are displayed in the list box. In the next window, there should be a drop-down list with all the names that are in the set of Individuals, but, as I said above, I could not create it.

I would like to know how to solve this problem.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# This code is a simplified version of a full program code. In the original program, there is not only a list
# of individuals, but also lists of team1, team2 ... team4.
# However, now I am only interested in the problems associated with individual list,
# and I cut out all the part of the code related to team.


class CollegeApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (IndividPage, listCheckPage, counterPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(IndividPage)
        self.lift()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


# In this  class I have created a window with entry widget to input name of individual and save it in
# eponymous set "Individual"

class IndividPage(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        headingTest = Label(self, text="Enter your User Name:", font="Arial 20")
        headingTest.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.usernameEnter = Entry(self, width=40)
        self.usernameEnter.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.TeamName = StringVar(self)
        self.TeamName.set("Individual")

        confirmBtn = Button(self, text="Confirm User", font="Arial 16",
                            command=self.confirm)

        confirmBtn.config(height=4, width=12)
        confirmBtn.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E, padx=45, pady=360)

# Checking the "add_to_team" function has been executed and moving to the next page.
    def confirm(self):
        if self.add_to_team():
            self.controller.show_frame(listCheckPage)

# Function to check the presence of input

    def add_to_team(self):
        user = self.usernameEnter.get()
        if len(user) == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning(title='No user', message='Please enter a username!')
            return
        if self.usernameEnter.get():
            self.controller.show_frame(listCheckPage)

        team_name = self.TeamName.get()
        team = teams[team_name]

        team.add(user)
        self.controller.frames[listCheckPage].team_listboxes[team_name].insert(END, user)
        print(teams)

# Class that creates page with lists of four teams and individuals (Focusing on individuals right now)
# Also there is two buttons "Add User" and "Start Counter" to start points calculator

class listCheckPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        self.team_listboxes = {}
        for col_num, teamname in enumerate(teams):
            teamMembers = Listbox(self)
            teamMembers.config(height=13, width=15)
            teamMembers.grid(row=0, column=col_num, padx=5, pady=50, sticky=S)
            for i, user in enumerate(teams[teamname]):
                teamMembers.insert(i, user)
            self.team_listboxes[teamname] = teamMembers

        INDHeading = Label(self, text="Individuals", font="Arial 16")
        INDHeading.grid(row=0, column=4, pady=0, padx=15, sticky=N)

        addUserBtn = Button(self, text="Add User", font="Arial 16",
                            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(IndividPage))
        addUserBtn.config(height=3, width=80)
        addUserBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=0, sticky=N)

        CounterBtn = Button(self, text="Start Counter", font="Arial 16",
                            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(counterPage))
        CounterBtn.config(height=3, width=80)
        CounterBtn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=0, sticky=N)

# Main problem  start here
# This class creating dropdown menu (or combobox) with sets "teamX" and "Individual" but it was unplanned
# I want this combobox to show not all possible sets (team1, team2 etc.).
# Instead of that I want the combobox will show all the names that were entered in the "Individuals" set.
# I would also like to point out that the same process will be used for the sets of team1, team2 etc.


class counterPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):

        indivLabel = Label(self, text="Please select an individual: ", font="Arial 20")
        indivLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

        IndivName = StringVar(self)
        IndivName.set(teams['Individual'])

        indivMenu = OptionMenu(self, IndivName, *teams)
        indivMenu.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

        backBtn = Button(self, text="BACK", font="Arial 16", height=2, width=6,
                         command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(IndividPage))
        backBtn.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=245, padx=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    teams = {}
    for team in range(1, 5):
        teams[f'Team{team}'] = set()
    teams = {'Team1': set(), 'Team2': set(), 'Team3': set(), 'Team4': set(), 'Individual': set()}
    pointsInd = []
    app = CollegeApp()
    app.geometry("800x500")
    app.resizable(False, False)
    app.title('Points Counter')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please shorten your code to only include the code that shows the problem? Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: By the way I suggest removing the `.geometry()` at least while You figure it out but the thing is that on the second page Individuals don't fit in the page which is why they are not seen.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I think I figured it out (I marked changes in the code with comments, they have a lot of "-" so that is how You will know (in total changes in 3 places (5 comments that have a lot of "-"))):

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# This code is a simplified version of a full program code. In the original program, there is not only a list
# of individuals, but also lists of team1, team2 ... team4.
# However, now I am only interested in the problems associated with individual list,
# and I cut out all the part of the code related to team.


class CollegeApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (IndividPage, listCheckPage, counterPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(IndividPage)
        self.lift()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        if cont == counterPage:  # changes here ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            frame.userEntry()  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


# In this  class I have created a window with entry widget to input name of individual and save it in
# eponymous set "Individual"

class IndividPage(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        headingTest = Label(self, text="Enter your User Name:", font="Arial 20")
        headingTest.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=5)

        self.usernameEnter = Entry(self, width=40)
        self.usernameEnter.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.TeamName = StringVar(self)
        self.TeamName.set("Individual")

        confirmBtn = Button(self, text="Confirm User", font="Arial 16",
                            command=self.confirm)

        confirmBtn.config(height=4, width=12)
        confirmBtn.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E, padx=45, pady=360)

# Checking the "add_to_team" function has been executed and moving to the next page.
    def confirm(self):
        if self.add_to_team():
            self.controller.show_frame(listCheckPage)

# Function to check the presence of input

    def add_to_team(self):
        user = self.usernameEnter.get()
        if len(user) == 0:
            messagebox.showwarning(title='No user', message='Please enter a username!')
            return
        if self.usernameEnter.get():
            self.controller.show_frame(listCheckPage)

        team_name = self.TeamName.get()
        team = teams[team_name]

        team.add(user)
        self.controller.frames[listCheckPage].team_listboxes[team_name].insert(END, user)
        print(teams)

# Class that creates page with lists of four teams and individuals (Focusing on individuals right now)
# Also there is two buttons "Add User" and "Start Counter" to start points calculator

class listCheckPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.userEntry()

    def userEntry(self):
        self.team_listboxes = {}
        for col_num, teamname in enumerate(teams):
            teamMembers = Listbox(self)
            teamMembers.config(height=13, width=15)
            teamMembers.grid(row=0, column=col_num, padx=5, pady=50, sticky=S)
            for i, user in enumerate(teams[teamname]):
                teamMembers.insert(i, user)
            self.team_listboxes[teamname] = teamMembers

        INDHeading = Label(self, text="Individuals", font="Arial 16")
        INDHeading.grid(row=0, column=4, pady=0, padx=15, sticky=N)

        addUserBtn = Button(self, text="Add User", font="Arial 16",
                            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(IndividPage))
        addUserBtn.config(height=3, width=80)
        addUserBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=0, sticky=N)

        CounterBtn = Button(self, text="Start Counter", font="Arial 16",
                            command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(counterPage))
        CounterBtn.config(height=3, width=80)
        CounterBtn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=0, sticky=N)

# Main problem  start here
# This class creating dropdown menu (or combobox) with sets "teamX" and "Individual" but it was unplanned
# I want this combobox to show not all possible sets (team1, team2 etc.).
# Instead of that I want the combobox will show all the names that were entered in the "Individuals" set.
# I would also like to point out that the same process will be used for the sets of team1, team2 etc.


class counterPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # self.userEntry() this method call seems to be useless -------------------------------------------------

    def userEntry(self):

        indivLabel = Label(self, text="Please select an individual: ", font="Arial 20")
        indivLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

        list_ = []  # changes here ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        for set_ in teams.values():
            for name in set_:
                list_.append(name)

        IndivName = StringVar(self)
        IndivName.set(list_[0] if len(list_) else None)
        indivMenu = OptionMenu(self, IndivName, list_)
        indivMenu.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)  # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        backBtn = Button(self, text="BACK", font="Arial 16", height=2, width=6,
                         command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(IndividPage))
        backBtn.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=245, padx=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # teams = {}
    # for team in range(1, 5):
    #     teams[f'Team{team}'] = set()
    teams = {'Team1': set(), 'Team2': set(), 'Team3': set(), 'Team4': set(), 'Individual': set()}
    pointsInd = []
    app = CollegeApp()
    # app.geometry("x500")
    # app.resizable(False, False)
    app.title('Points Counter')
    app.mainloop()
```

Basically I made it so that the userEntry function gets called when user gets to that frame instead when the class is initiated which means it will upadate every time someone switches to that frame, also made it so that it displays each name individually.

Also I suggest following PEP 8 and using `snake_case` for function, variable and method names and using `CapitalCase` for class names. And I suggest following other PEP 8 rules too (they are not mandatory tho)

Comment: It usually isn't a good idea to put code in methods that isn't obvious like your `frame.userEntry()` in `CollegeApp.show_frame`. It makes your code undebuggable because the caller will never know what is being called. Also did you notice how all of the `userEntry` functions are technically the same as `set_up_frame`. That is why OP used `self.userEntry()` inside `counterPage.__init__`. If I was you, I would revert the changes that you made to `CollegeApp.show_frame` and `counterPage.__init__`.

Comment: @TheLizzard hmm, where did  my comment go I am sure I wrote one already, anyways. about that obviousity is it really that bad in this case since a pretty specific condition has to be met before calling the method. Also no I did not notice them being same, I just noticed the button putting frame on the screen and followed that. Will try reverting that stuff

Comment: @TheLizzard what is `set_up_frame`? I didn't see such function in the code